# Javascript button onclick not creating record

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a custom java script button on `Account` object. Clicking the button should create `Case` (Child of Account) and `Issue__c` (Child of Case object) records.

`Case` record is created successfully, but `Issue` record is not created. Attached the error message screenshot.

Below is the javascript code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")}
var newcase= new sforce.SObject("Case");

newcase.Status = "New";
newcase.Origin= "Phone";
var result = sforce.connection.create([newcase]);
alert('A case has been created with number:'+result);
var newissue = new sforce.SObject("Issue__c");
newissue.Case__c = newcase.Id;
newissue.Name = "Name 1"
var result1 = sforce.connection.create([newissue]);
alert('A Issue has been created with number:'+result1);
window.location.reload();
```

Error screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the newly created `Case` id using the `result` variable.

In fact, the `create` method returns an array of type `SaveResult` as you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create_saveresult.htm).

This type contains an `id` variable and a `success` variable as boolean.

Here's the right code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")}
var newcase= new sforce.SObject("Case");

newcase.Status = "New";
newcase.Origin= "Phone";
var result = sforce.connection.create([newcase]);
if(result[0].success == 'true'){
   var newissue = new sforce.SObject("Issue__c");
   newissue.Case__c = result[0].id;
   newissue.Name = "Name 1";
   var result1 = sforce.connection.create([newissue]);
   if(result1[0].success == 'true'){
      window.location.reload();
   }else{
      alert('An error occurred during the issue creation');
   }
}else{
   alert('An error occured during the case creation');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this martin, though i updated the above code am getting the same error. Please advice.

Comment: What do you have exactly as error message?

Comment: getting the 1st alert that case has been created. in the second alert box - errors:{fields:'Case__c', message:'Required fields are missing: [Case__c]', statusCode:'REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING',},id:null,success:'false',}

Comment: Can you add an alert after this line: `var result = sforce.connection.create([newcase]);`. Please add: `alert(result[0].id);` and watch if the id is filled.

Comment: Yes, this has filled. but this is not getting assigned in this statement.. newissue.Case__c = records[0].Id;

Comment: Are you sure you copied right my code? Because the line is not: `newissue.Case__c = records[0].Id;`. Its: `newissue.Case__c = result[0].id;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54681/discussion-between-venky-and-martin-lezer).